# Как сделать задержку в ходе выполнения цикла?

Tags: java, android, while, sleep, android-threads

Необходимо сделать цикл, в котором происходит **выполнения действия** -> **задержка** (допустим секунда) -> **опять действие**.

Мои попытки приводят к тому, что действие выполняется, только все задержки "суммируются" и используются одновременно, что приводит к тому, что результат выводиться только к концу цикла.

```
    public void Add(View v){
        Run();
    }

    public void Run(){
        while(a!=5){
            a++;
            String b = String.valueOf(a);
            myList.add(b);
            name=myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]);
            RV.setAdapter(new Adapter(name));
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {}
        }
    }
```

Прошу помочь если не кодом, то советом/ссылкой на нечто подобное.

Comment: А где у вас там выводится резултат?

Comment: Возможно кто-то еще меняет переменную a (так как она, судя по всему глобальная).

Comment: опишите детально проблему

Answer (score 2):

В чем проблема? Ваш вариант вполне подходит. Можно немного красивее:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // Ваш код
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
}
```

Все происходит как Вы и хотите: **выполняется `Ваш код` -> задержка (1 сек) -> опять выполняется `Ваш код`**. И так 3 раза.

Comment: Немного неправильно вы меня поняли, сейчас дополню вопрос

Comment: Вот, пересмотрите код.. происходит так, что оно всё разом отображается, а не с задержкой каждая

Comment: Не могу знать где и что у Вас там отображается, так как не знаю что за объект `RV` и что происходит в методе `setAdapter`. Задержка должна быть, Вы просто ее "не ощущаете". Метод `sleep` принимает миллисекунды. Следовательно, Вы устанавливаете задержку в 0.1 сек. Попробуйте увеличить значение до 1000 - 5000.

Comment: RV- RecyclerView

Comment: Если увеличить время, то ничего не меняется, разве что меняется задержка

Comment: Вообщем, цикл который Вы хотели - есть (Вы и сами его предоставили). А почему у Вас такое странное поведение, по тому куску кода, что Вы предоставили, никто Вам не скажет. Такое поведение возможно только в многопоточном приложении. Общий ответ таков - Вы что-то не так спроектировали.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, буду искать решение